# Why does MySQL query not return newest row

Tags: mysql, sql

I got specific query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stats 
WHERE mod_name = 'module' 
GROUP BY domain 
ORDER BY addition_date DESC
```

I want to retrive, the newest value for every domain. I know there is a domain x.com value with date 2014-02-19.

However, this query returns me row with date: 2014-01-06

That's quite simple query... why it does not take group by domains and take only newest value?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `order by` takes place *after* the `group by`.  That is why your query does not work.  Here is a way to get what you want:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stats s
WHERE mod_name = 'module' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from stats s2
                  where s2.mod_name = s.mod_name and
                        s2.addition_date > s.addition_date
                 )
ORDER BY addition_date DESC;
```

To get the best performance, create an index on `stats(mod_name, addition_date)`.

Comment: So that's why my results are completly random. TY!

Comment: I created a bit different query, without exists.
Wouldn't this one be faster?:
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM stats WHERE mod_name = 'module' ORDER BY addition_date DESC) as ab
    GROUP BY domain ORDER BY addition_date DESC

Comment: You are using a `group by` extension that is explicitly documented not to work:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.  Plus, the query with `not exists` and the appropriate index should be faster, because it doesn't require sorting the original data.